# How can I get the status of an sql agent job?

Tags: sql-server

We use an sql agent job running on our SQL 2000 server to import data from our business system every ten minutes. The job runs a number of steps and usually takes about 5 to 6 minutes to run. This data is used for various packing processes.

This will usually run with no problems but on occasion we have problems where a step will get 'stuck' which means we do not get new data from the business system.

I would like to display the status of the job on a screen in our office so we can see if there is a problem. Is there a query I can perform on the database to return the status of a job, if it is running, which step it's on, how long it's been running and when it is next scheduled to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will give you the status of all jobs and should be supported going forward, otherwise using the msdb..sysjobhistory should do the trick.

```
exec msdb..sp_help_job -- gives you all jobs and a status for each
exec msdb..sp_help_job @job_id = 'job_id GUID from sysjobs'
exec msdb..sp_help_job @job_name = 'job name'
```

Comment: Thanks, slight change to get just the data I need, EXEC msdb..sp_help_job @job_name = 'job name' ,@job_aspect = N'job'

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Agent logs job data to  [msdb..sysjobhistory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174997.aspx) You can use that table to track the success/failure of the job and job steps & see if its running.

You can use [msdb..sysjobschedules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188924.aspx) to work out next scheduled run time.

Comment: Using msdb..sysjobhistory I can see if a job or step has executed and the outcome but I can't see if it is currently executing.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following query often to determine what is currently running on a SQL server.  It won't be specific to what agent is running but it gives you an idea of what specific query or queries are currently executing:

```
USE Master
GO
select text, * from sys.dm_exec_requests CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS s2 order by 1
GO
```

Comment: you can't use those dmv's in sql server 2000